# convertir en negativo valor dentro de un setter java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(!("TB").equals(this.cabnom.getTipo())){
            ArrayList<Linnom> lista = (ArrayList<Linnom>)this.linnomService.findByNumNom(new Linnom(numNomAnterior));
            for(int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++){
                Linnom linnomActual = lista.get(i); 
                linnomActual.setNumnom(numNomDuplicado);
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC());//negativo
                linnomActual.setPrecioC(linnomActual.getPrecioC());//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaV(linnomActual.getCantTomadaV());
                linnomActual.setPrecioV(linnomActual.getPrecioV());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCD(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCD());//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCH(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCH());//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVD(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVD());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVH(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVH());
                linnomService.create(linnomActual);
            }
        }
```

y quiero convertir en negativo los valores dentro del set. los valores que quiero convertir a negativo son de tipo Double. he intentado ésto pero no me muestra los valores ¿Alguna idea?

```
if(!("TB").equals(this.cabnom.getTipo())){
            ArrayList<Linnom> lista = (ArrayList<Linnom>)this.linnomService.findByNumNom(new Linnom(numNomAnterior));
            for(int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++){
                Linnom linnomActual = lista.get(i); 
                linnomActual.setNumnom(numNomDuplicado);
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(-(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()));//negativo
                linnomActual.setPrecioC(-(linnomActual.getPrecioC()));//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaV(linnomActual.getCantTomadaV());
                linnomActual.setPrecioV(linnomActual.getPrecioV());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCD(-(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCD());//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCH(-(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCH()));//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVD(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVD());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVH(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVH());
                linnomService.create(linnomActual);
            }
        }
```

Comment: si es un double, no lo puedes multiplicar por -1 en vez de ponerle un - delante? o sea, hacer esto: linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(-1*linnomActual.getCantTomadaC());

Comment: Haz esto: **`linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()*=-1);`**, o sea, aplicas **`*=-1`** a aquéllos números que quieres convertir en negativos.

Comment: Si pruebo linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()*=-‌​1); me sale éste error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: El igual no es necesario con aplicar esto bastaria linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()*(-‌​1));

Comment: Es cierto, puedes hacerlo solamente así, dado que es un `getter`: **`linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()*-1`**. He actualizado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplicar el valor por `-1` lo convierte en negativo.

De modo que si haces algo como esto debería funcionar:

```
if(!("TB").equals(this.cabnom.getTipo())){
            ArrayList<Linnom> lista = (ArrayList<Linnom>)this.linnomService.findByNumNom(new Linnom(numNomAnterior));
            for(int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++){
                Linnom linnomActual = lista.get(i); 
                linnomActual.setNumnom(numNomDuplicado);
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaC(linnomActual.getCantTomadaC()*-1);//negativo
                linnomActual.setPrecioC(linnomActual.getPrecioC()*-1);//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantTomadaV(linnomActual.getCantTomadaV());
                linnomActual.setPrecioV(linnomActual.getPrecioV());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCD(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCD()*-1);//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaCH(linnomActual.getCantPedidaCH()*-1);//negativo
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVD(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVD());
                linnomActual.setCantPedidaVH(linnomActual.getCantPedidaVH());
                linnomService.create(linnomActual);
            }
        }
```

Esta operación funciona con todos los primitivos (y con algo más :)).

Veamos una prueba: [<kbd>VER DEMO</kbd>](http://rextester.com/CMR85519)

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int intTest=3;
        double dblTest=1.8;
        byte bitTest = 100;
        short shtTest = 10000;
        float fltTest  = 123.4f;
        char chrTest = 'Z';

        System.out.println(intTest*-1);
        System.out.println(dblTest*-1);
        System.out.println(bitTest*-1);
        System.out.println(shtTest*-1);
        System.out.println(fltTest*-1);
        System.out.println(chrTest*-1);
    }


}
```

**Resultado:**

```
-3
-1.8
-100
-10000
-123.4
ﾦ
```

Comment: *= lo que hace es guardar en la variable que haya a la izquierda el valor de la misma multiplicada por lo que haya a la derecha, no funciona con un getter porque no es una variable.

Comment: Corregido @PabloLozano

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo. Me salta una nullpoiinterException, porque **linnomActual.getCantPedidaCH();** es null, y al multiplicarlo por -1 salta una excepción.

Comment: @missrobot entonces tendrás que establecer un control de nulos en el getter por ejemplo para que en esos casos te devuelva `0` u otro valor válido.